# setup Azure Application Gateway the same as nginx reverse proxy

Tags: azure, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, azure-application-gateway

This is my current nginx config which works the way I want.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.key;

    location /domain-folder1 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5678/;
        include proxy_params;
    }
    location /domain-folder2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4151/;
        include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

I tried to setup the Application Gateway with the same logic as nginx but nothing worked so far.

I thought Path based rules should work but they dont.

Answer (score 0):

I created sample nginx proxy and setup to Azure application gateway.

[image]

To setup the Application Gateway with the same as nginx, created application gateway added backend pool as defined in the servers or endpoints to which the requests will be forwarded for each of your backend services.

[image]

Add routing rule and backend setting, you can create a listener for port 443 and associate the appropriate SSL certificate. Specify the server name to match the host header in the incoming requests.

[image]

[image]

Add [health probe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview#custom-health-probe) to configure correct custom domain name as its host name like below:

In host add name of virtual host running on the application gateway server

[image]

Verify backend health of web application are in healthy state, it redirects with server successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

To know more in detail, check the below references:

[Using Microsoft Azure Load Balancers and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-and-azure-load-balancers-on-microsoft-azure/)

[Azure-docs/articles/application-gateway/configuration-request-routing-rules MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/configuration-request-routing-rules.md)